# Making HTML responsive in email

Tags: html, email, mobile

I wrote some code for an email advertising campaign my company is about to launch.Code works great on a computer screen, problem is when I load it on my phone, the code is blown up! Is there away to better epitomize my html code?

I would have to use CSS I know, but I cant just attach it to the email, so I need do some inline stuff.

any ideas?

I am using div tags, h1 tags as well as the standard html stuff. I am using px to dictate the size of my images, should I use percent values? But when I do, if someone re-sizes a window on a desktop, it gets all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ink. They make it easy to create responsive HTML emails. Similar to frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation (CSS framework by the company that created Ink).

http://zurb.com/ink/
http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php